# Laravel passport oauth multiple database connection

Tags: api, laravel-5, oauth, oauth-2.0

So, I'm building this api where each client use the same system (controllers, models). Each client has his own database and a website that connect's to this database.

Now that's the problem, this api must serve all this websites with different database connections and since I'm new to Laravel, I'm facing a hard time. What's the best way to do that?

Should I save each database in a file (for example client's id is 1, so we have a folder with a file named 1.env with database info)?

PS.: I'm using oauth2

Comment: Your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, I'll post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was: each client with his own database and a folder with "users" and a subfolder for each client. Inside, a file with database info, in login we use a global table that indicates where's the database from that user. Next step is load the database connection and check user/password. That was a quick solution.

However in my research  I stumped into "multi tenancy" thing that seams way better, you can find it more [on this link](https://hackernoon.com/simple-multi-tenancy-with-laravel-b3f84fc13c39).

Comment: here is my question, Can you please check?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594676/laravel-passport-gives-401-unauthenticated-error?noredirect=1#comment82151397_47594676