# Laravel passport gives 401 Unauthenticated error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel passport for API authentication, it works perfectly when I use it with one DB, but gives `401` when using multiple databases,

What I'm doing:

- I have a multi-tenant DB, master DB have users, roles and all OAuth tables.
- When I create a user with admin role it will create new DB with admin name, it will create sub DB with users, roles and all OAuth table. `oauth_clients` of sub DB will copy Password Grant Token and Personal Access Token from master DB and insert in sub DB, and also insert `client_id` in `oauth_personal_access_clients`.
- I'm doing all the procedures which `passport:install` command does. (If I'm not missing something).
- When I login with credentials from master DB it works perfectly, the real problem starts when I login with credentials from sub-database, I can get sub DB from a param `client_code` which I input with `email`,`password` while login.
- It allows me login from sub DB but I get `401 Unauthenticated`  error, get Access token while login and I pass `Authentication` Header with `Bearer` on every request after login from `Angular` front.
- Don't know what I'm missing here.

**DBConnection Middleware**

DBConnection middleware  sets connection on every request after login,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( $request->method() != 'OPTIONS' ) {            
            $this->access_code = $request->header('access-code'); 
            if ( $this->access_code != '' && $this->access_code != 'sa'  ) {
                app('App\Http\Controllers\Controller')->setDB(AppHelper::DB_PREFIX.$this->access_code);
            } else {
                app('App\Http\Controllers\Controller')->setDB(AppHelper::DB_DEFAULT);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

`DBConnection` sets default DB in `database.php` dynamically, for that, I'm calling `setDB` method created on `Controller.php`

**setDB Controller.php**

```
public function setDB($database='') {
      $config = app()->make('config');
      $connections = $config->get('database.connections');
      $default_connection = $connections[$config->get('database.default')];
      $new_connection = $default_connection;
      $new_connection['database'] = $database;
      $config->set('database.connections.'.$database, $new_connection);
      $config->set('database.default', $database);
  }
```

Is it possible to use `passport` with 2 different DB for same code?

`Laravel 5.4`
`Passport 4.0`
`Angular 4.4` in front-end

Comment: How do you switch between databases and what is inside your header exactly? It sounds like an issue with one of these.

Comment: @tprj29 I created a middleware which sets db config, I am passing a db name in route params, I don't think its problem with that as login works perfectly, but problem arise after login, it starts giving 401 error, using Angular 4 on front

Comment: This really sound like a header issue, because the header `Authentication` is only needed after login. And since login and getting the bearer token works perfectly according to you. Can you show us what value your header `Authentication` has.

Comment: @tprj29 Authorization is same as passed from login

Comment: code would help because it is hard to see where it goes wrong without anny codesnips

Comment: @tprj29 Code added to question, can you please check?

Comment: try adding a search_path query see my answer for details.

Comment: Laravel passport is only working with User as a provider. Even if you fetch token by adding above changes with PasswordGrant & UserRepository, while you go for API call for Post and get requests are not working with changed passport provider other than User.

Better you create multi auth with session driver if must needed as Vendors and Customers. let 'User' model only for passport whose table columns supports admin, API, vendor, etc.

Repo here https://github.com/storesbuzz/laravel-multiAuth

Comment: https://github.com/jsdecena/laravel-passport-mutiauth

Comment: Perhaps you need use an User that extends from Authenticatable and use traits HasApiTokens. Also, it's probably you need develop your own login authentication.

Comment: This issue could be the order of the middleware, check to make sure the DBConnectionMiddleware is before the passport auth middleware

Comment: If you use Auth::attempt works fine?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Yes you can!

In our middleware we do some like this:

```
config([
  'database.connections.tenant.schema' => $tenant
]);

DB::connection('tenant')->statement("SET search_path = $tenant");
```

It really sounds to me that your search_path is not set up in properly. This would explain why you get a **401**. Because Laravel Passport is searching in the wrong database in which it can't find the right token in your users table.

From PostgreSQL docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html):

> ## search_path (string)
>
> This variable specifies the order in which schemas are searched when an object (table, data type, function, etc.) is referenced by a simple name with no schema specified. When there are objects of identical names in different schemas, the one found first in the search path is used. An object that is not in any of the schemas in the search path can only be referenced by specifying its containing schema with a qualified (dotted) name.

Comment: I'm not using `PostgreSQL`, I'm using `Mysql`

Comment: In your model that handles the query can you log the connection which is used? I think the connection is not properly managed inside the models.

Comment: If I don't use `passport` connection works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS issue. OPTIONS request does not deliver Authorization headers.

If the origin is different from the host, browser going to send OPTIONS before any other request.

Laravel going to answer with the status 401 if CORS middleware is not set up.

So with RESTful architecture, if the client app host is different from the API's host you have to use CORS middleware.

You may use this one:
[barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

Example:

**App\Http\Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'auth.cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ...
];
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api',
    'middleware' => [
        'auth.cors'
    ]
], function () {
    Route::post('user/authenticate', 'UserController@authenticate');
});
```

If CORS middleware works properly a browser shall receive status 200 on the OPTIONS request and fire the initial request with a payload.

Comment: He is not sending an `OPTIONS` request - his middleware is checking methods **other** than `OPTIONS`